# how to install turtlebot simulator in virtualbox?

Tags: ros, installation, turtlebot, ros-fuerte, virtualbox

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear,

I just installed VirtualBox Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with ROS Fuerte. After that, I would like to install turtlebot simulator, but found that the tutorial is for electric version. I got stuck at the first step: Configure your Ubuntu repositories to allow "restricted," "universe," and "multiverse" but I cannot see any Software Sources or Software Center. Just wondering if turtlebot can run on Fuerte or not? Or is it the problem of VirtualBox and the LTS version? Thank you very much indeed for your help.

best regards,
David

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50756/how-to-install-turtlebot-simulator-in-virtualbox?/) by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2012-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question has been answered by NooTriX. Using their OVA, configuration is not required. Just type:

sudo apt-get update

download and install all the updates, and then type

sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-turtlebot-simulator

Simple!!!

---

Originally posted by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) with karma: 229 on 2012-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-12-19**:
@Chik Could you get it working ? turtlebot simulator is developed on gazebo and gazebo has issues with Virtual Box !!!

**Comment by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on 2013-01-08**:
Yes in Virtual Box ROS Fuerte provided by Nootrix I can launch turtlebot simulator in an empty world and control it using keyboard.